# What does the integral over the spectral function tell you physically?

Tags: superconductivity, greens-functions

I am playing around with some plots right now, and have some interesting looking results, but I am unsure how to read them. First, I am using the following real space BdG Hamiltonian:
$$    \hat{H}= -\sum_{\boldsymbol{r},\boldsymbol{r}',\sigma} t(\boldsymbol{r}-\boldsymbol{r}')
    \hat{c}^\dagger_{ \boldsymbol{r}\sigma}\hat{c}_{\boldsymbol{r}'\sigma}
    +\sum_{\boldsymbol{r},\boldsymbol{r}'}\Big(\Delta(\boldsymbol{r},\boldsymbol{r}')
    \hat{c}^\dagger_{ \boldsymbol{r}\uparrow}\hat{c}^\dagger_{\boldsymbol{r}'\downarrow}
    +\text{h.c.}    
    \Big) $$
I am using ARPES fitted parameters for LSCO and a gap of .06 eV. We can find the FT of the Green function:
$$ 
G_\sigma(\boldsymbol{r}_i,\boldsymbol{r}_j,t)=-i\theta(t)
\big\langle \big\{\hat{c} _{ \boldsymbol{r}_i\sigma}(t),\hat{c}^\dagger_{ \boldsymbol{r}_j\sigma}
\big\}\big\rangle 
$$

into frequency and k-space, then find the spectral function:
$$
A(\boldsymbol{k},\omega)
    =-\frac{1}{\pi }\text{Im}\Big(G(\boldsymbol{k},\boldsymbol{k},\omega) \Big)
$$
I attached a few plots here, which look nice, but I was wondering if anyone can explain the spectral sum rule? That is what does the integral over all energies of this spectral function tell us physically?

I think this integral should be proportional to an expectation value of the anti-commutator of FTs of our above creation and annihilation operators. Intuitively it tells us the occupation of certain k-states, $n(\boldsymbol{k})$, and so this seems in line with this. I am just having trouble connecting to these plots! Nothing more than having fun here and curiosity, but would be nice to know!
[image]
[image]
[image]